I have few nfts and tokens in my babt smart contract wallet,I need to transfer those to a normal wallet
I have this wallet, on bep20, bscscan.com, i need help with
0x029Bab9a3191A4270EbE5Bd210670Ee6F0DcA94E
Which has one nft erc 721 in bep20, and somehow it has an associated wallet
0x2B09d47D550061f995A3b5C6F0Fd58005215D7c8
I need help with transferring tokens and nfts to my walllet ,
and #CT95 chat gpt provided a code and told me it is easier to interact with it via website, but unfortunately does not fully understand or there is some problem, do you think you might be able to teach someone hard head like  me or help me transfer,
thanks in advance

Do you have any confused here? I did a check on etherscan, and both address which you provided are wallet. No one is a NFT. Btw, if you want to transfer to your wallet but not confidence, just transfer them one by one. Or you can upload the contract which chatgpt suggest you, everyone can help to confirm

Thank you very much for your answer, the second address i provided is actually NFT we receive after KYC with Binance, and i am 99.9 percent sure it is an NFT, you could see it on bscscan, would you like to see the contract i received from chatgpt

Oh I see, I checked it on ethereum network for instead. Please edit your question to include network detail and the contract code from chatgpt.
